Android TextInputEditText Multiline
Iam looking for a TextInputEditText to support multiline text.
The TextInputLayout implemented in an alertdialog.
I tried everything... How to do ? :/
Thanks a lot!
example of my code:
val editText = TextInputEditText(requireContext())
                editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE
                editText.maxLines = 4
                editText.setText(value ?: "")
                val maxLength = 100
                editText.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(LengthFilter(maxLength))
                editText.addTextChangedListener(FieldTextWatcher(columnName, dat))

                val textInputLayout = TextInputLayout(requireContext())
                textInputLayout.addView(editText)
                textInputLayout.hint = title

This is when typing... enter image description here
and this is when edittext lost focus enter image description here

Add
    editText.isSingleLine = false

output

